# Calculate probability. Balls picking

Tags: probability, combinatorics

*Lets say that there is 20 balls. 8 of them are red, 8 blue, 4 white. What is the probability that if person picks 6 balls he picks 2 red and 3 blue?*

Any hints would be appreciated

My solution:
$\binom{8}{2} * \binom{8}{3} * \binom{4}{1} \over \binom{20}{6}$

That is $6272 \over 38760$

Comment: How $8+8+6=20$????? You want hints, at least make sure you publish the information correctly (let alone showing some effort trying to solve it)!!!

Comment: sorry my bad, there are 4 white balls

Comment: What about the $6$th ball? Is it white?

Comment: 6th ball should be white

Comment: You've got it correct now; I'll remove my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

Your solution is correct. The fraction reduces to $\frac{784}{4845}$.